# a bit map in c++ - will unsigned int do the job?

Tags: c++, c, bitmap, unsigned-integer

I'm afraid to admit, I haven't used C++ for a while now but i'm afraid I have to now, and I'm a bit rusty.

I need to have a bitmap, and I do care about performance, my bitmap size will be no longer then 25 bits.

I was thinking about using unsigned int, but I am afraid I do not remember how it is implemented in c/c++


Is unsigned int implemented as a regular binary number? 

I am also open to any other suggestions for a bitmap.

thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: According to [this thread on meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6254/) we are called *Stackers*, not *overflowers*. :)

Comment: Why is this tagged `C`? In `C` `unsigned int` is guaranteed to have 16 or more ints; you need `unsigned long` with 32 or more bits.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use an `std::bitset<25>` from the header `<bitset>`. `bitset` can be indexed with `[]` and is a template, so it likely expands to just an `unsigned int` (or equivalent) with all operations inlined.

Comment: are the performance for it good? especially I need to check a lot of times if all bits are clear.

Comment: @amit: it's a template class, so performance is likely the same as rolling your own or better.

Comment: @amit I think it will probably compare favourably than your Java!!

Comment: @amit, the `any()` method allows you to test this, I'd hazard there is little difference between calling this and a compare against 0.

Comment: @David, that might be the reason I don't do it in java.

Comment: Actually, the `none` method is a more direct way of checking for all bits zero.

Comment: @Nim,Iarsmans - thanks. I'll check it out and come back to tell how that went.

Comment: one more thing, does std::set compares between 2 bitsets efficiently and correctly?

Comment: @amit: You mean `std::bitset`? Yes, just use `==`.

Comment: @amit: if you do mean `std::set`, then not directly; there is no "less than" operator defined for `std::bitset`. However, you can write a simple comparator to compare the values of `bitset.to_ulong()` (or `bitset.to_string()` if the bitset is too large to fit in an `unsigned long`, but that would be much slower).

Answer (score 4):

Have you considered [std::bitset](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/bitset/) from `<bitset>` header file?

Example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <bitset>

int main() {
        std::bitset<25> bits(146);
        std::cout << bits << std::endl;

        //using operator[] to access individual bit manually!
        for(size_t i = 0 ; i < bits.size() ; ++i)
           std::cout << bits[i] << " ";
        return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
0000000000000000010010010
0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

**Note:** `bits[0]` is the least significant bit, while `bits[bits.size()-1]` is the most significant bit!

Online demo : http://ideone.com/3sSF0

Answer (score 0):

consider a [bitset](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/bitset/) instead.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use an integer type for a bit map, assuming it has enough bits for you.

However, there is a `<bitset>` in the standard library.